# In what version of Android was process caching first implemented?

Tags: cache, processes

Android can cache app processes to improve start-up times for subsequent app executions.

You can see this capability on some devices by going to `Settings->Applications->Manage Applications` (or just `Settings->Apps` on others), going to the "Running" applications tab, and either pressing the `Menu` button or another button on the UI marked with the option to `Show cached processes`.

Here's a list of devices I've looked at to see if this "Show cached processes" menu item is available:

- HTC Hero (Android 2.1-update1) - No
- HTC T-Mobile MyTouch 3G Slide (Android 2.1-update1) - No
- Samsung Dart (Android 2.2) - No
- HTC EVO 4G (Android 2.3.3) - Yes
- HTC EVO Shift (Android 2.3.4) - Yes
- HTC EVO 3D (Android 4.0.3) - Yes
- Samsung Nexus S 4G (Android 4.1.1) - Yes
- Samsung Galaxy S3 (Android 4.1.1) - Yes

Based on these devices, it looks like process caching became visible to the user in Android 2.3.

So, the question:

- In what version of Android was process caching first introduced (even if its not visible to the user)?

Any answers with strong evidence (e.g., Android documentation or AOSP source code references, 1st person observations of devices) are appreciated.

Comment: Am not 100% sure, but this looks *borderline*... ?